# vendor and product id of a mounted/unmounted usb device

Tags: linux

How to get vendor id and product id and mount point of a mounted/unmounted usb device in linux?

Answer (score 2):

Try `lsusb`, it should list all you usb devices.

Comment: but it will not give the mount point?

Comment: No, it won't show mount point. That could be hard if it's unmounted anyway... :)

Comment: so, is there any way to find attached usb devices and their mount points?